# Как к существующему элементу List, добавить еще значения, или поменять значение?

Tags: c#, list

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Users> lol = new List<Users>();
    lol.Add(new Users("maks", "kovtun", 234234, "учасник"));
    lol.Add(new Users("Jeka", "SKRT", 32552, "активований"));

}


[Serializable]

public class Users
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public int ID;
    public string Status;
    public string Username;
    public Users() { }
    public Users(string fName, string lName, int id, string username )
    {
        this.FirstName = fName;
        this.LastName = lName;
        this.ID = id;
        this.Status = status;
        this.Username= username;
    }
```

1. Как в процессе в  List который содержит ID 234234 добавить еще юзернейм?
2. Как в листе который содержит ІD 234234 поменять поле участник на активный ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lol.Find(t => t.ID == 234234).Username = "еще юзернейм";
lol.Find(t => t.ID == 234234).Status = "активный";
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас получается что-то типа шаблона Repository, коллекция в памяти.

Тут важны две вещи:

1. Как вы будете искать записи. В простейшем случае используйте LINQ, либо можете создавать набор методов для поиска типа FindById, FindByName и прочие.
2. Как вы будете устанавливать значения. У вас начальные значения ставятся через конструктор, а дальше? Вам либо делать геттеры/сеттеры, либо отдельные методы писать типа SetUserName и т.п.

Самый банальный способ модифицировать ваш пример:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Users> lol = new List<Users>();
    lol.Add(new Users("maks", "kovtun", 234234, "учасник"));
    lol.Add(new Users("Jeka", "SKRT", 32552, "активований"));

    lol.First(x => x.ID == 32552).FirstName = "wow";
}


[Serializable]
public class Users
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public int ID;
    public string Username;
    public Users() { }
    public Users(string fName, string lName, int id, string username)
    {
        this.FirstName = fName;
        this.LastName = lName;
        this.ID = id;
        this.Username = username;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё. Пример выше -- просто показать направление. Продумайте, как вы будете обрабатывать ситуацию, когда в хранилище у вас не будет записи с ID = 123. В коде выше вы либо получите исключение в First, либо (если бы там стоял  FirstOrDefault) получили бы null reference при попытке обращения к FirstName.

Поэтому более правильно проверять, есть ли такой элемент:

```
var elem = lol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 32552);
if (elem != null)
{
    elem.FirstName = "wow";
}
```

Comment: а что за метод `Dump`? Откуда он у Вас?

Comment: @per Я код писал в linqpad'е, это его отладочный метод -- скриншот как раз оттуда. Убрал, дабы не смущать.